# Bash prompt customize

Tags: bash, customization, prompt

I'd like to customize my bash prompt so, that when the exit code of the last command is not 0, a frown would appear on the of the row.

This is what i came up with so far, but for some reason, I get always a frown

```
export PS1='\[$(tput sc; if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
     printf "%*s" $COLUMNS " :)"
   else
    printf "%*s" $COLUMNS ":("
   fi; tput rc)\]\[$(tput bold)\]\u@\h\[$(tput sgr0)\] \A [ \w ]\n\[$(tput bold)\]\\$\[$(tput sgr0)\] '
```

(Everything is on one row)

Comment: Take a look at bash's special variable `$PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `tput` is the last command, it alters the exit code, see the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tput).